# Setup audit trail has unexplicable entries

Tags: lightning, setup-audit-log

I've noticed a couple of strange entries in our setup audit trail - one of our support team apparently created two Lightning pages at 5:52am on March 8th

[image: Setup Audit Trail]

Except he claims he didn't.  We're not a Lightning-Enabled org, have no Lightning Apps and he reasonably asserts he wasn't even awake at this time.

The Login history for this user seems to agree too

[image]

So the questions are - where/how do I see these items and how would they have been created if he didn't do it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55901/discussion-between-rob-cowell-and-ashwani).

Comment: So I've since discovered these items via the metadata API as "Flexipages" even though I can't see them in the Setup UI on the org itself.  They're the default utility bars for Sales Console and Service Console BUT it still doesn't explain how they were created, given the user that the audit trail claims to have done it was asleep at the time and is unlikely to have done it.  Also, if they were created automatically by an upstream SFDC release process, why that user in particular and why only in my Prod org?

Comment: Salesforce Support have stated that this was an update rolled out by the Spring 17 release "and found a random System Admin User to tag as the owner of the change. It was unfortunate that the user was someone who has not logged in during those times." but it doesn’t explain why these pages don’t exist in our Spring ’17 sandboxes, only in Production. Surely an automated upgrade to Spring 17 would cascade the same release across all orgs.  They're continuing to investigate but thought it may be useful to post update on this question in case anyone else was seeing this behaviour.